# Trying to invoke play on DLNA-device with streaming from Synology NAS

Tags: video, nas, streaming, dlna

I am trying out the DLNA protocol for the purpose of invoking media on my LG TV, where the media is stored on a Synology NAS (hosted with Media Server) on the same network.

I have successfully found the TV device and the NAS, and enumerated the mp4-videos I want to play on the TV.

Setting `SetAVTransportURI` seem to work without error but I am very unsure about the metadata-parameter. In any case as soon as I invoke Play I get a cryptic ComException: 0x80040365

The media-uri is accessible through a browser, and the TV can itself find and play the videos through its own media player.

I read somewhere that LG-tvs are very specific with the response headers:

```
contentFeatures.dlna.org: DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000
transferMode.dlna.org: Streaming
```

But when inspecting the headers I could only find `transferMode.dlna.org: Streaming` and not the other one. Have been trying to figure out how to add this header somehow without much success. One approach that seemed promising was to setup a custom reverse proxy host to point to the DLNA-port, and also add the missing header here. But this isnt working very well. For once I cannot add a header with dots like `contentFeatures.dlna.org` because the form doesnt accept it. But when trying to add something else like just `contentFeatures` it still wont show up in the response. Its as if it is just removed again. But I still dont even know if this is the problem.

Anyone else who have tried this and found the same problems?

Can I add this header some other way on Synology NAS with Media Server?

Any idea on what the error could be otherwise?